# Why can't I get out of display mirror mode?

Tags: linux, xorg, amd-radeon

I've been running Ubuntu (10.04.1 LTS, 64-bit) for a while and just replaced my hardware with a faster machine with an ATI Radeon HD 5700 video card.  I've got twin 1920 x 1080 displays.  I downloaded the latest driver (ati-driver-installer-10-9-x86.x86_64.run) from the ATI web site and installed that.

I've gone through a few rounds of playing with /etc/X11/xorg.conf, and can't get things right.  At the moment, it's in display mirroring mode, and I can't figure out how to get it out of mirror mode.  If I run Monitor Preferences, there's a "Same image in all monitors" checkbox.  If I uncheck that, the little preview window switches to show two monitors.  When I click Apply, it asks me to log out and log back in again.  When I do that, I'm right back to mirrored mode.

What's really weird is that I'm currently running a copy of xorg.conf from a coworker's machine.  He's got identical hardware, and his display works fine.  So, I'm inclined to think there's something else going on other than the conf file.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: first, you should first tried installing drivers from repo, second, try amdcccle, third: question would be much better at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Are you running "Monitor Preferences" as root?

Answer (score 1):

Backup your config. Then try making a new one using **aticonfig**

```
aticonfig --initial=dual-head --desktop-setup=horizontal --screen-layout=left --xinerama=on
```

Test that out and compare the two to see what you want to add to your old config.